# Goのexecでコマンドの途中経過を表示させたい

Tags: go, shellscript

Goの[os/exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/)を使ってコマンドを実行しその途中経過を表示させたいと考え http://qiita.com/hnakamur/items/9701f40c1fec83b1cd1f と https://github.com/hnakamur/execcommandexample を参考にさせていただきました。

しかし、このプログラムで実行している`a.sh`は以下のようになっていまして

```
#!/bin/sh
echo out1
sleep 1
echo err1 1>&2
sleep 2
echo out2
echo out3
sleep 1
echo err2 1>&2
exit 1
```

出力の間に1秒間のスリープが入っています。スリープがあれば正しく表示されますが、これがないと非決定的な動作をします。
スリープを覗いた状態でも正しく表示させたいのですが、何か方法はありますでしょうか。以下に上記サンプルの実行結果を示します。

**sleepあり**

```
stdout:out1
stderr:err1
stdout:out2
stdout:out3
stderr:err2
stdout result:out1
out2
out3

stderr result:err1
err2

exitCode:1
```

**sleepなし1**

```
stdout:out1
stdout:out2
stdout:out3
stdout result:out1
out2
out3

stderr result:err1
err2

exitCode:1
```

**sleepなし2**

```
stderr:err1
stdout:out1
stderr:err2
stdout:out2
stdout:out3
stdout result:out1
out2
out3

stderr result:err1
err2

exitCode:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goステートメントを削除したところ決定的な動作になりました。

https://github.com/hnakamur/execcommandexample/blob/master/main.go#L53 
https://github.com/hnakamur/execcommandexample/blob/master/main.go#L54

上記コードのgoを消した。

Answer (score 0):

コードと結果をセットで提示していただけますか？また期待する結果がどれにあたりますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。自己解決しました。単純にゴルーチンが必要なかったようです。